# Want to kill the event while the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, events, touchstart

I have a requirement where I want to kill the same event (`touchstart`), while the button is pressed and held for some time (for iOS).

```
  $("#btn").on("touchstart", function(evt){
     currBtn = $(this);
     timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>{
        changeOpacity(currBtn);
     }, 1500);
     return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a work out solution. You just need to change the `mousedown` event for the `touchstart` event:

```js
function changeOpacity() {
   $("#btn").css("opacity",0.3);
}

function addEvent() {
    //add the event
    $( "#btn" ).on("mousedown",onTouchStarts);
}

function removesEvent() {
    //removes the event
$( "#btn" ).off("mousedown",onTouchStarts);
}



function onTouchStarts(evt){
  console.log("mousedown");
  currBtn = $(this);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>{
    changeOpacity(currBtn);
    removesEvent();
  }, 1500);
  return false;
}

addEvent();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `preventDefault()` this suppresses any default behaviour that would normally be triggered

```
evt.preventDefault();
```